# Explicitly add @2x to non retina devices

Tags: ios, retina-display

We have a mystery !

In our app we use only retina images (@2x marked).
Until yesterday non-retina devices showed the images well even when we called the images without @2x at the end.

For example if the file name is 'fun@2x.png' we called `[UIImage imageWithName:@"fun"]`.

Today it stopped working and now we have to call `[UIImage imageWithName:@"fun@2x"]` for the image to display. (The device is iPhone 3GS iOS 5.1).

We are now afraid that we don't understand something about the retina naming.

What changed ?
What is the correct way to deal with it?

Thanks

Shani

Comment: You missed the @ symbol for the file name strings (e.g. @"fun"). Is it a typo?

Comment: Yes it is a typo, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should provide non-retina images! The downscaling isn't a good option. The problem here is that iOS tries to find the fun.png image and doesn't find it. Therefore can't present something.

I have no explanation why it worked before. Are you sure?

Comment: It is a compromise as we have a 45 mega binary. if we will add the non retina then we will over the 50MB limit of wifi downloads. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: I marked this as this is as the correct answer as this is the official answer by apple.

Answer (score 2):

In apps I have worked on if I am only supplying 1 image (the 2x one) than I just use the full image name, ie:

```
[UIImage imageWithName:@"my-image.png"]
```

When I am supplying images for certain buttons that I need have 2 versions of, I use:

```
[UIImage imageWithName:@"my-image"]
```

Doing it this second way, you **must** supply a retina & non-retina image with that base name

Like [dasdom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14056867/480415) said it should have not been working before that way-- and even if it somehow was you should stick to what I said above if you want your images to always display.

Comment: Well it works well for almost an year. I don't have an explanation fo that.

Comment: @shannoga Many strange unexplainable things happen in Xcode I have come to learn :P